# how to iterate over the properties of object in scala?

Tags: scala

Is there some way i can iterate over the properties of object and get the name and value both while iterating.
I know about the [product iterator](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Product), but using that I only get the property value not the name of the property at the same time.

Comment: What do you want to do in the end? This seems to be an instance of the [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem)

Answer (score 3):

Unless you are building tooling for programmers developing scala, it is very probable that you should be using a `Map` instead of an object.

eg:

```
val myObject: Map[String, Any] =
  Map("prop1" -> 1, "prop2" -> "string", "prop3" -> List(1, 2, 3))

for ((key, value) <- myObject) {
  println(key, value)
}
```

If you *are* building tooling or you can't just swap out the object for a map, you can use reflection as mentioned in the other answers.

Answer (score 2):

Just don't do it!

Use another design: Scala is not PHP or Python or Perl; it's a statically typed functional language with a very expressive type system; such reflection (runtime inspection) is not needed 99.9% of the time and should be avoided for reasons of safety, correctness and performance.

Comment: I believe this question concerns the 0.1%-cases.

Answer (score 1):

I think, there is no way to do it without using reflection. (See for example here: [Getting public fields (and their respective values) of an Instance in Scala/Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7457972/getting-public-fields-and-their-respective-values-of-an-instance-in-scala-java))

An other option is using Apache FieldUtils: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/reflect/FieldUtils.html But again it uses reflection in background.